# convert uint to string is possible now in solidity?

Tags: solidity

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract GoTekERC721 is ERC721, Ownable {

    constructor() ERC721("Go NFT", "GoN") {}

    //Owner to Phone
    mapping(address => uint256[]) public phones;
    //change
    // Phone to Balance
    mapping(uint256 => uint256) public balance;
    

    function register(uint256 phone, uint256 Balance) public {
        _mint(msg.sender, phone);
        phones[msg.sender].push(phone);
        balance[phone] = Balance;
    }

    
     function details(address owner) public view returns(string memory) {

        uint256[] memory ownerPhones = phones[owner];

        mapping(uint256 => uint256) storage userBalances;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < ownerPhones.length; i++) {
            uint256 phone = ownerPhones[i];
            userBalances[phone] = balance[phone];
        }
         return userBalances; 
    }
}
```

in solidity 0.8.9 it gets error.i don't understand what can i do to convert my mapping to string and get o/p like {"phone":"Balance","phone":"Balance"} ...thanks in adanced

Comment: Please edit the question and post the code as text (you can use markdown syntax or the `{}` symbol in editor to format a code block), so it's easier for answers to copy-paste parts of your code and troubleshoot.

Comment: sorry to change my code ....@PetrHejda

Comment: 1. You probably shouldn't be storing phone numbers on the block chain.  2. You can't return mapping it its in memory only. 3. There is no owner phones member.  to solve this just create a struct with `uint256 PhoneNumber, and uint256 balance` and copy the values to it and return it as numbers and not strings

Comment: but i want phone:balance , in front of phonenumber:balance  please guide or send me a sample code to understand @johnny5

Comment: Why? process and string manipulation should just be done off chain.  You're wasting money trying to format or do string manipulation

Comment: if you really wanna do that use [strings.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol)